# custom module to have an admin form

Tags: extensions, forms

I want to create a module with a form when clicking on menu tab, I have tried to exactly create it like what we have under System->MyAccount, 
but when I click on Example the menu is empty.I started with [this example](http://alanstorm.com/2013/projects/Pulsestorm_Adminhello.tar) and changed it.
here is my effort:
[image]

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Adminhello>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Custom_Adminhello>
    </modules>
        <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhello>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Custom_Adminhello</module>
                    <frontName>admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhello>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <custom_adminhello>
                <class>Custom_Adminhello_Helper</class>
            </custom_adminhello>
        </helpers>
         <blocks>
            <custom_adminhello>
                <class>Custom_Adminhello_Block</class>
            </custom_adminhello>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml:

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <custom translate="title" module="custom_adminhello">
            <title>Custom Module</title>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <children>
                <example>
                    <title>Example</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhello/system_account</action>
                </example>
            </children>
        </custom>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>                
                    <custom translate="title" module="custom_adminhello">
                        <title>Example Menu Item</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <example>
                                <title>Example Menu Item</title>
                            </example>
                        </children>
                    </custom>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>

</config>
```

AccountController.php

```
class Custom_Adminhello_System_AccountController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('System'))->_title($this->__('My Account'));

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('system/account');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhello/system_account_edit'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }


}
```

Data.php:

```
class Custom_Adminhello_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Edit.php:

```
class Custom_Adminhello_Block_System_Account_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_controller = 'system_account';
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('adminhello')->__('Save Account'));
        $this->_removeButton('delete');
        $this->_removeButton('back');
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return Mage::helper('adminhello')->__('My Account');
    }
}
```

Form.php

```
class Custom_Adminhello_Block_System_Account_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $userId = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
        $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')
            ->load($userId);
        $user->unsetData('password');

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Account Information')));

        $fieldset->addField('username', 'text', array(
                'name'  => 'username',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Name'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Name'),
                'required' => true,
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('firstname', 'text', array(
                'name'  => 'firstname',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('First Name'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('First Name'),
                'required' => true,
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('lastname', 'text', array(
                'name'  => 'lastname',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Last Name'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Last Name'),
                'required' => true,
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('user_id', 'hidden', array(
                'name'  => 'user_id',
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('email', 'text', array(
                'name'  => 'email',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Email'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('User Email'),
                'required' => true,
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('current_password', 'obscure', array(
                'name'  => 'current_password',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Current Admin Password'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Current Admin Password'),
                'required' => true,
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('password', 'password', array(
                'name'  => 'new_password',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Password'),
                'title' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Password'),
                'class' => 'input-text validate-admin-password',
            )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('confirmation', 'password', array(
                'name'  => 'password_confirmation',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Password Confirmation'),
                'class' => 'input-text validate-cpassword',
            )
        );

        $form->setValues($user->getData());
        $form->setAction($this->getUrl('*/system_account/save'));
        $form->setMethod('post');
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setId('edit_form');

        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html  extension its free and simple. Try and mark ans as correct.

Comment: have you placed xml file in app/etc/module

Comment: yes it is there